# Nested Query: SELECT within INSERT Query

Tags: python, tornado, psql

I have two tables say Doctors and patients. I need to fetch the doctors id (unique) from the doctors table and then pass it to a column of the patient's table during the INSERT operation. How can I write the query for that.

I tried the below way but it gives programming error:

```
  usr = self.current_user
 self.db.execute("INSERT INTO patients ("SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE doctors.id = '%s' " % usr )(mrd, name, age, gender, address, phone_number, blood_group,\
        registration_date, did) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s')" % (mrd,name,age,gender,\
        address,phoneNumber, bloodGroup,dateOfReg,usr),callback=self.add_response)
```

I am trying to execute this in python tornado framework with psql backend

Answer (score 0):

1. `SELECT` should be in `VALUES` section
2. The query will be like so

`doctor_id = self.db.execute("SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE doctors.id = '%s' " % usr ).fetchone()
self.db.execute("INSERT INTO patients(mrd, name, age, gender, address, phone_number, blood_group,registration_date, did, doctor_id) values (%s, %s, %s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s, %s)" % (mrd,name,age,gender,address,phoneNumber, bloodGroup,dateOfReg,usr, doctor_id),callback=self.add_response)`

Comment: Could you show how exactly to write the SELECT in VALUES. Becuase I tried the below way and I am still not getting an answer.

Comment: @Athira It's easier way, or you can paste `SELECT` query instead `doctor_id`, I mean at the end of all passing variable

Comment: self.db.execute("INSERT INTO patients (mrd, name, age, gender, address, phone_number, blood_group,\
            registration_date, doctor_id) values ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s','%s','%s','%s','%s', '%s')" % (mrd,name,age,gender,\
            address,phoneNumber, bloodGroup,dateOfReg,doctor_id=("SELECT id FROM doctors WHERE doctors.id = '%s' " % usr )),callback=self.add_response)

I added the following but it shows invalid syntax

Comment: Yes, because you can't-do so.